# Why did Daniel have to negotiate with the Russians for a DHD?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

Early in the series, they discover a second gate under the Antarctic, complete with a DHD. Later, the DHD is shown to function through a rogue team using the second gate. Even later, the Russians acquire the second gate (well, actually, the first, but that's a bit of a story), but use a DHD they got from the Germans at the end of World War II.

So, the SGC should still have the Antarctic DHD somewhere - but there is a crisis with the gate, and Daniel is sent to negotiate for the Russian DHD. Why? What happened to the American DHD?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From ["Dial Home Device", *wikia*](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Dial_Home_Device#Earth.27s_DHDs) specifically the section "Earth DHD's" it states that the Antarctic DHD ran out of power due to it being extremely old (one of the oldest found in the Milky Way) so it could not be used. They still had it but it was inoperable at the time of the crisis.

I imagine that they probably would have been able to fix it, however there was a timing concern with Teal'c being stuck in the pattern buffer of the gate and they needed another DHD quickly.

It should be noted too that getting Teal'c from the stargate using the DHD from the Russians resulted in the DHD being destroyed, leaving none on Earth.

Comment: I think they were only renting it from the Russians as well, which must not have gone down well.

Comment: No, the negotiation at the time was the dhd for a permanent Russian team at SGC. It was a trade not a loan.